# How do I get AWS S3 credentials from Nodejs to Angulajs securely?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My application uploads photos to S3 from the client side, but the way I get credentials is not the best way.

In Angulajs I make a GET request to the NodeJS server to retrieve the credentials, but this is turning the credentials public.

```
$http.get("/aws_creds/").success(function (result) {
    creds = result;

    // Configure The S3 Object
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: creds.access_key,
        secretAccessKey: creds.secret_key
    });
    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
    bucket = new AWS.S3({
        params: {
            Bucket: creds.bucket
        }
    });
});
```

How do I get the credentials more securely?

Comment: The best thing to do is sign a URL that can then be uploaded to.  Be careful though, there isn't a good way to enforce upload size.  What might look like a 50kB JPEG at signing time might actually be 50TB of garbage.

Comment: Is this Angular app running in an AWS Lambda? And is the NodeJS server calling an AWS API Gateway?

Comment: No, its hosted on heroku